# resium (cesium-react) camerafly end at same zoom level/camera altitude as starting position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cesiumjs

Well I have a react component using resium where the camera can move dynamically based on data.

```
const imgProvider = new OpenStreetMapImageryProvider({
    url : 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/'
});
function TrackingMap(props) {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState({longitude: 4.3571, latitude: 52.0116});
    const startCoordinates = Cartesian3.fromDegrees(data.longitude, data.latitude, 10000);
    const pointCoordinates = Cartesian3.fromDegrees(data.longitude, data.latitude, 0);
    function move() {
        setData((old) => {
            return {longitude: old.longitude+0.00025, latitude: old.latitude};
        })
    }
    setTimeout(move, 200);

    return <div>
        <Viewer
            full
            resolutionScale={0.5}
            baseLayerPicker={true}
            fullscreenButton={false}
            homeButton={false}
            sceneModePicker={true}
            selectionIndicator={true}
            timeline={false}
            animation={false}
            geocoder={false}
            imageryProvider={imgProvider}
        >
            <Camera />
            <CameraFlyTo
                destination={startCoordinates}
                duration={0}
            />
        </viewer>
    </div>
}
```

This would follow the point however each time it would reset the altitude of the camera. How can I prevent that and allow free zooming while sticking the camera to the dot?